# Percent Increase, groupby, over time (using Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have a dataset, df, where I am trying to calculate the percent increase of a particular group over a time period. Here is the dataset:

```
    date      size       type

   1/1/2020   1          a
   1/1/2020   1          a
   1/1/2020   3          a
   1/1/2020   1          b
   1/1/2020   2          b
   1/1/2020   0          b
   2/1/2020   5          a
   2/1/2020   6          a
   2/1/2020   3          a
   2/1/2020   20         b
   2/1/2020   21         b
   2/1/2020   30         b
```

Desired output

```
  date         increase   diff   type

  1/1/2020     200%       2      a
  1/1/2020     -40%      -2      a
  2/1/2020     -100      -1      b
  2/1/2020      50%      10      b



Percent Increase/Change is  final-inital/initial * 100

example for a , we start at 1 then end at 3, 
which is a 200% increase in the month of January
```

This is what I am doing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df1=df.groupby(['type', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='1D')])['size'].sum()
df1['increase'] = df1['size'].pct_change().mul(100)  
df1['diff'] = df1['size'].diff()
```

However, my dates are not grouping correctly. Since I only have dates that are consecutive first of the month, I figure I can just use freq = '1D'

```
    date             

   1/1/2020            
   1/1/2020             
   1/1/2020             
   1/1/2020
```

I suppose I would have to groupby the type as well as the date, but I am not sure and I am still researching this.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**Updated**

I have a dataset, df, where I wish to calculate the percent increase of the sum of a particular group over a time period. Here is the dataset:

```
     date     size       type

1/1/2020     1          a
1/1/2020     1          a
1/1/2020     1          a
1/1/2020     2          b
1/1/2020     5          b
1/1/2020     6          b
2/1/2020     20         a
2/1/2020     21         a
2/1/2020     10         a
2/1/2020     1          b
2/1/2020     4          b     
2/1/2020     5          b
```

Desired output

```
(grouping by type and date to find sum)

date        size    type

1/1/2020    3       a
2/1/2020    51      a
1/1/2020    13      b
2/1/2020    10      b
```

I believe this will do it for the first part:

```
    df.groupby(['date','type']).sum()
```

(finding the increase and diff by type)

Final Desired Output:

```
 date        type      increase    diff
 
 2/1/2020    a         1600%       48    
 2/1/2020    b        -23.07%      -3



Percent Increase/Change is  final-inital/initial * 100
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the difference of this and your previous question? for e.g. how do you define final and initial for group `a` since they only multiple same `date`. Is it that for groups of `date`s you pick the last index as final and first index as initial?

Comment: Thank you. I was getting confused on the dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a simple groupie aggregation function:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['type','date'])['size'].agg(lambda x:(x.iloc[-1]/x.iloc[0]-1)*100).to_frame('increase')
df1['diff'] = df.groupby(['type','date']).agg(lambda x:x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
df1.reset_index()
```

output:

```
  type      date  increase  diff
0    a  1/1/2020       200     2
1    a  2/1/2020       -40    -2
2    b  1/1/2020      -100    -1
3    b  2/1/2020        50    10
```

**UPDATE**:

if you want to plot per `type` increases:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
groups = df1.groupby('type')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group.date, group.increase,marker='o',linestyle='',ms=12,label=name)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

**UPDATE2**: Per OP's update on the post:

```
df = df.groupby(['type','date']).sum().reset_index()
df1 = df.groupby(['type'])['size'].agg(lambda x:(x.iloc[-1]/x.iloc[0]-1)*100).to_frame('increase')
df1['diff'] = df.groupby(['type']).agg(lambda x:x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
df1['date'] = df.groupby(['type']).date.max()
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

output:

```
  type     increase  diff      date
0    a  1600.000000    48  2/1/2020
1    b   -23.076923    -3  2/1/2020
```

Comment: Hi @Ehaan is there a way to completely group the a and b in a single output? Like a total increase for a given date is : value etc?

Comment: @Lynnette I am not sure if I understand the question. Do you want to separate `a` and `b` into two different data frames or do you want to multi-index them? maybe you can add it to your question with sample desired output?

Comment: Ok I will - I will write this out. I am wanting to create  a scatter plot for each type over a time period. - right I think to add them to different data frames is the solution. I will update the post. Thank you

Comment: Oh wow @ehsan yes this does. I will use same logic to implement plotly graph to add interactivity. Thank you for your knowledge and help

Comment: HI @ehsan, could you please look at my updated post when you can

Comment: Please disregard. You have provided correct answer. I will update and delete the 'update'

Comment: Yes thank you @Ehsan - I will learn and research this- does it matter if the dates are sorted or not for this to work?

Comment: @Lynnette yes. you can either sort by date or inside aggregate lambda function, instead of choosing by iloc, use max and min date to select the row.

Comment: you are welcome. deleting some unnecessary comments to keep the post clean.

Comment: Is there a way to include date in the 2nd output you just provided? @ehsan?

Comment: @Lynnette which dates do you want to include? each group `type` is associated with more than one date.

Comment: I was wondering if the latest date associated with that group could be included in the output. I was not sure if this was possible. I am researching this @ehsan

Comment: @Lynnette Please check the edit on post to include latest date per group type. I would suggest for future questions on SO to form the question to a good extent to avoid back-forth editing. Thank you.

Comment: Ok my apologies, @ehsan, but I do have it listed as the final output in the update. Thanks